# How to change the number of results to display in aspx site

Tags: python, asp.net, parsing, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to parse aspx site. And now I am stucked at the displying results limit which is set to 90 per search. It seems the limit is set here:

```
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ScriptManager1', 'aspnetForm', ['tctl00$MainContent$upFilter','MainContent_upFilter','tctl00$MainContent$UpdatePanel1','MainContent_UpdatePanel1'], [], [], 90, 'ctl00');
//]]>
```

Is it possible somehow to send a request and get all the results?

Site: https://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/CEIDG.Public.UI/Search.aspx#
Thank you!

Comment: You don't know if that is just a default value. The server side code written in c# may very well persist it own value. Given this is asp.net, then viewState and session() are used to persit server side c# code - and you may well not be able to change those values, or in fact they may not be used in the SQL code that pulls the data. Given that asp.net code behind is strong typed c# (or vb.net) code, then often the variables and code used is managed 100% server side, and you can't access/set those values from client side. That value might only be the pager size - not # of rows pulled from sql

Comment: Hello Albert! Thank you so much for your reply! So there is no solution, except to form search query to get less then 90 results right?

Comment: I really can't say. All I am pointing out that asp.net sites have server side code behind, and often variables and values for that code to work may well not be exposed client side.  So, it still might be possible - but without a deep dive and looking at that site, I can't take all bets off the table.  Due to the way asp.net works, often code will even test/check if a id or some value don't match, and ignore as such. Also, some controls on the page may well use view state and thus a change client side does not always persist for some controls. So, a solution may still exist, but I can't say.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Albert!